# callerPrincipal should give no result when started by ejb timer

Tags: ejb, glassfish-3, jaas

This code normally gives us the currently logged in user. 
But when the method is started via a ejb timer there is no user. 
It should give back null or a exception. 
But i heard from the colleges that we get another random user from the context. How can this happen?

```
@Resource
private EJBContext ejbContext;

ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
```

Does anybody have experience with this code started via a ejb timer?

Answer (score 0):

The EJB 3.0 specification (and newer) says:

> The EJB container must provide access to the caller’s security context
>   information from the enterprise beans’ instances via the
>   `getCallerPrincipal()` and `isCallerInRole(String roleName)` methods. The
>   EJB container must provide the caller’s security context information
>   during the execution of a business method invoked via the enterprise
>   bean’s business, home, component, or messsage listener interface, web
>   service endpoint, and/or `TimedObject` interface, as defined in Table 1
>   on page 79, Table 2 on page 88, Table 3 on page 117, Table 4 on page
>   197, and Table 10 on page 269. The container must ensure that all
>   enterprise bean method invocations received through these interfaces
>   are associated with some principal. If the security identity of the
>   caller has not been established, the container returns the container’s
>   representation of the unauthenticated identity. The container must
>   never return a null from the `getCallerPrincipal` method.

Therefore in your specific case I would expect to see "the container’s representation of the unauthenticated identity". If you do not see this then I would expect that there is some configuration (possibly via a GlassFish specific deployment descriptor) missing in your application.